# how do i solve Geopandas error using SCHEME argument

Tags: python, dictionary, geopandas

When i use code in python below, it doesn't work.

```
df.plot(figsize=(14,10),linewidth=0.5, edgecolor='black', column='count', cmap='Reds', scheme='quantiles', k=5, legend = True, alpha = 0.9)
```

[df is like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bZ9N.png)

when i use this code -> `df.plot()`
the result is as below.
[result of "df.plot()" code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DazrS.png)

when i use this code -> `df.plot(column = 'count')`
the result is as below.
[result of "df.plot(column = 'count)" code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKswg.png)

I am experiencing an issue where an error occurs only when using the 'scheme' argument. The error message indicates that the process takes too long to execute, making it impossible to view the result. I would like to understand why this problem is happening and learn how to resolve it. Could you please assist me? Thank you already.

same as the content written above.

Comment: Could you also share the dataframe `df` you used for the plot or a reproducible copy of the data?

Comment: added on the posting!!!!

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I was thinking of have the raw data instead of screenshot so it's easier to reproduce the error on my end if possible